# How do I use an excel function inside a custom function defined in VBA?

Tags: function, vba, call, rounding, defined

How do I use an excel function inside a custom function defined in VBA?

I want a custom round function that acts like MRound and RoundDown. To round to the nearest 25 millionths.

```
Public Function MRoundDown(Num As Double) As Double

Num = Num * 40000
Num = RoundDown(Num, 0)
Num = Num / 40000

End Function
```

Comment: You can access a lot of functions via Application.WorkSheetFunction, you can try something like Num = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(yourVariableHere)

Comment: I know, I already figured out the answer but I couldn't post it for another 7 hours.

Answer (score 3):

I already figured it out myself, but it took entirely too long to find the help that I needed. So here's the solution.

The problem in trying to use RoundDown was that I had not specified the library to call that object from. Application is Excel, WorksheetFunction is where the RoundDown object is defined.

```
Public Function MRoundDown(Num As Double) As Double
Num = Num * 40000
Num = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(Num, 0)
Num = Num / 40000
  MRoundDown = Num
End Function
```

I further improved the code like this:

```
Public Function MRD(Num As Double, Multiples As Double) As Double
Num = Num / Multiples
Num = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(Num, 0)
Num = Num * Multiples
MRD = Num
End Function
```

There's one more level of functionality that I could hope for, to be able to accept a percentage input and then be able to RoundDown only if the remainder is lower than x percent of the multiple. For instance given .25 as multiple, and .8 as the percentage, I would want it to round 1.19 to 1.00 and 1.20 to 1.25.